# Where to store local video for playback in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-videoview

I am making a simple video playback application in Android Studio. The video is approximately 600MB, and has an appropriate title (no spaces etc.). The video will be played back using VideoView.

Where should the video be saved? When it is placed in src/res/raw, (like other files I am using such as .wav for sound effects), it creates resource errors. Do I create a new folder called assets and store the videos there?

Comment: _Where should the video be saved?..._ Definitly not on the device... wondering how big your app will be at the end...

Comment: @B001 is there a recommended easy way to stream? Should I use Firebase?

Comment: The place is `raw`. Please, post your logcat here for us to see the pointed errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noooo. You will not put that video in your apk. Will your app exceed 600mb size on playstore. See on [google documentation.](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files)

> Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than 100MB

**Solution:**

- First try to **compress your video**, as you don't need high resolution video.
- **Put video on cloud** (like Amazon s3 bucket).
- **Download this video file at run time** in device from Amazon. And then play it anywhere from device storage.